# What is the shortcut to skip all break-points in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints, shortcut

When I am at a breakpoint and if I want to ignore all the rest of breakpoints and move on, what shortcut should I use?

Comment: Really good question but I can't see a single answer that really answers the question, i.e. skipping all breakpoints, **not** disabling them.

Comment: @mrt I agree. Place to vote: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13276296-continue-but-temporarily-ignore-active-breakpoints

Comment: Indeed, after discovering Godot allowed it, I searched for this in VS but it seems the only alternative not to lose your breakpoints setup is to Detach process and Reattach later... not ideal. By the way, the uservoice page is no longer available. All I could find was this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/please-add-a-feature-to-disable-all-breakpoints-to/926795 and the replies from both bot and human don't really make sense (they talk about it as if it was a bug, not a suggestion). Finally I found https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W836 from Visual Assist X, but it's paid.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can select "**Disable All Breakpoints**" from the **Debug** menu.

This and then continue with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

You could set this up as a keyboard shortcut under *Tools/Options/Keyboard*.

Comment: thanks! It was useful and quick to implement.
You can also assign a shortcut for "Enable All Breakpoints"
I have used CTRL + 7 for disabling and CTRL + 8 for enabling. Most of the shortcuts are reserved already.

Comment: You need to set Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints or Debug.EnableAllBreakpoints

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012 it's slightly different. You can set up your own breakpoints by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.

Comment: If you have Resharper and struggled to find 2 free shortcut keys for Disable/Enable All Breakpoints, I've used [[ Ctrl + Shift + ` ]] for Disable
, [[ Ctrl + Alt + ` ]] for Enable

Comment: Really strange that they went with separate shortcuts for enable and disable instead of just making a single one for toggling them all on/off...

Comment: Great, I choose Alt+B to enable and Shift+Alt+B to disable. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Well, you can:

1. **delete** all breakpoints using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
2. **disable** all breakpoints from the ->Debug menu.

Disabling breakpoints does not have a shortcut defined, but you define your own in ->Tools->Options menu under Environment->Keyboard. Also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> stops debugging altogether.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> will delete them all.

To disable all breakpoints - either you do it from the menu - or you go to option -> environment -> keyboard, and create a shortcut there.

Answer (score 6):

Enabled / Disabled **just one break point** at a time with **Ctrl + F9**.

Though the cursor has to be on the given line of code.

Answer (score 2):

By default there is no option available to Disable/Enable all breakpoints, so you need to add it. Steps to add Disable/Enable breakpoints are as :-

1. Under **Tools** tab select **Customize**.
2. Then under **Commands** tab, you would find 3 options(drop-downs) - **Menu bar**, **Toolbar** and **Context menu**.
3. So under **Menu bar** drop-down, scroll down and select option **Debug**.
4. And now under **Controls** section, select the command you need to add i.e here you would select command **Enable All Breakpoints/Disable All Breakpoints** and click **Add Command**.
5. Close this pop-up and boom, now you would find this option under **Debug** section of the main console.

Answer (score -2):

Shortcut to delete all break-points: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? The short cut which I am suggesting is not correct for deleting breakpoints?

Comment: Sorry, I meant The OP asked., how could he disable all break points.(Not to delete all break points).

Comment: i.e Disable/Skip, so that he could add it later