# Can you skip remaining breakpoints in debug mode in Visual Studio 2017/2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, breakpoints

When I'm debugging an application and I have numerous breakpoints all over the place, if I have finished debugging the part I'm interested in, is it possible to then ignore all the remaining breakpoints and run the application?

I don't want to delete them or disable them permanently - kind of just a quick keyboard shortcut to say yeh I'm happy with the current bit of debugging and I want to check the output before moving on to the next.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Seems like the easiest (and possibly only) option is to disable/re-enable all as needed, although it was asked a while ago: [What is the shortcut to skip all break-points in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833855/what-is-the-shortcut-to-skip-all-break-points-in-vs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortcut to skip all break-points in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833855/what-is-the-shortcut-to-skip-all-break-points-in-vs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the breakpoints to ignore all the remaining breakpoints.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Although I use "VS code", it is similar in VS

Debug > Disable all breakpoint.

When you want to enable
Debug > Enable All breakpoint.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019:
If you just want to disable them go to Debug and disable them there.
If you want to set up a keyboard shortcut go to Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard then in the input box titled Show commands containing: type disable
You should see Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints there, you can set a new shortcut for this and use it.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, you can choose Disable breakpoints from Debug tab in visual studio to skip rest of the breakpoints.